# Can I Use MS-Access in back end instead of MYSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

I want to use `MS-Access` on the place of `MYSQL` in my C# .net software's, so is this possible to use `Access as an back end` in web based and windows based software's/applications.

Please help me out.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible (at least in the Windows application with a local copy), but why do you want to use Access instead of MySQL?  Access is generally not considered a "serious" database.   Especially when so many more robust options are available at little to no cost.

Comment: Actually i want to get my software's online in my server and as server has an OS of windows then i can easily use access over their instead install sql server over their and then use it.

Comment: I would strongly suggest SQL Server Express vs Access for a Windows server.  If you're dead-set on Access, then put access on the server and see if your app can connect.

Comment: ohk thanks for your suggestions #Tim.

Comment: History has shown me that mutli used access can have an issue of corruption if its multi used. if you really dont want to use their SQL server express assuming you dont need more than the limitations it has, will suit you great.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, for both cases. However, to use Access for a web application is just begging for trouble. Personally, I would never consider it. For a Windows application, it can work very well, depending on many factors (you will need to do some research). With a stand-alone application (like built in C#) you do not need to install Access. Just the correct drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Access for any kind of web-based thing.  Use SQL Server Express.  Something like the code below should work fine for you.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection sqlCnn ;
            SqlCommand sqlCmd ;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            int i = 0;
            string sql = null;

            connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
            sql = "Select * from product";

            sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                sqlCnn.Open();
                sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn);
                adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0] + " -- " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
                }
                adapter.Dispose();
                sqlCmd.Dispose();
                sqlCnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```